# Change a TextView when my Timer reaches a random time

Tags: java, android

Here is what I have so far

```
long startTime = 0;
TextView timerTextView;
final Handler timerHandler = new Handler();

Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        int seconds = (int) millis / 1000;
        int minutes = (int) seconds / 60;
        seconds %= 60;

        int min = 40000;
        int max = 49999;
        long randomTime = (long) (Math.random()*(min-max) + max);

        timerTextView.setText(minutes + ":" + seconds);

        timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 500);
    }
};
```

I want to know how I can use the `randomTime` variable to trigger my `TextView` to change to say Time Is Up. I found a way to create a scheduled task using the following:

```
timerHandler.postAtTime(Runnable r, randomTime);
```

The only problem is I don't know what `Runnable` I should use to cause the `TextView` to change.

Comment: What is your requirement exactly

Comment: I want to change the text of timerTextView when the Timer reaches a certain time that is randomly selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all put the `randomTime` outside of the thread,

```
int min = 40000;
int max = 49999;
long randomTime = (long) (Math.random()*(min-max) + max);
```

Create a simple handler that'll run after the time specified by `randomTime` variable,

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                // handler has reached the time
                // now update the TextView using a runOnUiThread
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                // Update UI elements

                // get the current time now
                long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                int seconds = (int) millis / 1000;
                int minutes = (int) seconds / 60;
                seconds %= 60;

                //finally update the TextView
                timerTextView.setText(minutes + ":" + seconds);

                   }
                });

                }
            }, randomTime);
```

Comment: Thank you Prokash. With just a little editing I was able to make it work,